# GoogleApiClient not adding scopes

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-games, google-api-client

My problem is that the GoogleApiClient is not adding the Games Scopes correctly.
It worked fine until a PlayServices 8.1

Here is the code that initializes the ApiClient

```
if (GameUtils.isGooglePlayGamesEnabled()) {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            // I also tried: .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.GAMES))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mApiClient.connect();
}
```

And here is the screenshot showing that no permissions are being asked despite the scope being the games scope.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen to be on Android 6.0?

Comment: Nope. Lollipop 5.1 and Kit Kat 4.4